# How to create scheduled query that writes to new table everyday?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a query that I want to run every day, but the results need to be populated to a new table each day due to the amount of data each table will contain (~10B rows/day).

Essentially want to write to a new table like: `my_database_name.my_table_name.my_results_{today's_date}` each day.

I see the feature that allows creating a "Scheduled Query" but don't see any option to write to a new table each day.

Is this possible to do in BigQuery? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query parameters to achieve this:

`my_database_name.my_table_name.my_results_{run_date}`

More detail can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#available_parameters_2